# Custom abbreviation snippet not expanding past first element in Emmet Sublime Text 3

Tags: json, sublimetext3, emmet

I am new to Emmet. Trying to create a custom abbreviation that expands to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.domain.com/path/CSstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.domain.com/path/CDstyle2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.domain.com/path/DEstyle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so I can easily insert a set of styles and script for a site I work on a lot.

I am working in Sublime Text 3 and went to Sublime > Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings - User and added the following as a starting point:

```
{
    "snippets": {
         "html": {
            "abbreviations": {
                "lclinks": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://www.domain.com/path/CSstyles.css\" />+<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://www.domain.com/path/CDstyles.css\" />"

            }
         }
    }
}
```

Which worked, but did not expand past the first style reference.  I tried replacing the `+` with an `n\t\` with the same results.  I found an example online and plugged that in instead to see if that worked, but it still does not expand past the first element.  What am I doing wrong?  The documentation [here](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) doesn't really address multiple line snippets.

```
        {
            "snippets": {
                 "html": {
                    "abbreviations": {
                        "lclinks": "<div class=\"block\">\n\t<div class=\"text\">\n\t\t<h3>|</h3>\n\t\t<p></p>\n\t</div>\n</div>"

                    }
                 }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are using `abbreviations` section which is actually parses provided *single element* HTML tag to use it as a reference for building output. And what you are trying to do is to create a regular *text snippet*. E.g. a chunk of arbitrary code.

If you read closer [snippets.json](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) section, you’ll see that given file contains `abbreviations` and `snippets` sections that has different meanings, described [here](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/types/).

In your example, you have to use either `snippets` section or use [aliases](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/types/#aliases) in your `abbreviations` section:

```
{
    "snippets": {
         "html": {
            "abbreviations": {
                "lclinks": "link[href=http://www.domain.com/path/CSstyles.css]+link[href=http://www.domain.com/path/CDstyle2.css]"
            }
         }
    }
}
```